# iOS 8: unicode of death, how does it work?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, malware

Once sent by message to an iPhone, the victim's device will turn off. (I was skeptical about it but I tried it and the code worked.)

This is the an image of the message from Cult of Mac:

[image: image here]

Can someone tell me how does it work and why?

Comment: It's not malware. It's just a bug in the unicode encoding. But this is off-topic.

Comment: what are the outcomes? @Huey

Comment: See [Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/323949/unicode-of-death-got-you-down-heres-how-to-fix-it/) for details.

Comment: You fool, you just opened the doors of Minas-Morghûl! We're all doomed!

Comment: this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont give me credits for the answer, see the source from where I got the info at the bottom.

From I what have read, basically happens at machine code, there is a Null value pointer validation on a OS X base library that renders text, which by the the way of the unicode characters are ordered (not completly sure), the pointer ends up containing a low address out of the boundaries of the application, which causes the OS or kernel to detect the exeption and terminating the process that was trying to render the text.

Check the source that I have read for a more detailed answer:http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/05/27/text_message_unicode_ios_osx_vulnerability/

Also, something similar happened at 2013. If you are also interested on the previous issue, see this small article: http://m.hexus.net/tech/news/software/59497-simple-arabic-text-string-instantly-crashes-os-x-108-ios-6-apps/